# If it is copying a file from USB 3 to USB 3, is the speed half or does it depends on the device's design?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3

I think I have copied files from a USB 2 hard drive to another USB 2 hard drive before, and the speed of copying is about half of what it would be if it is copying from the computer's hard drive to the USB 2 hard drive.

So I thought the bandwidth of USB 2 is probably "shared" or "split".  However, today I copied a file from a USB 3 hard drive to another USB 3 hard drive and I was able to get 100MB / s, so the speed doesn't seem like "half". But I just checked the USB 3's bandwidth is 5Gbit / s, which is about 500MB / s.

So

1. Is it true that usually, it is "half"?
2. Unless if the design is that the USB 3 ports are based on different PCI controllers, but that's less likely on a home machine or NAS
3. So the reason it didn't seem "half" is because the hard drives are the bottleneck: they can only go up to 100MB / s read or write... so the "half speed which is 250 MB / s" limit didn't affect them

Is that how it works?

Answer (score 2):

A USB controller can have a maximum bandwidth, so if you connect 2 USB devices to the same USB controller, the speed could be halved. If you connect the USB disks to 2 USB ports that are not on the same USB controller, the speed should in theory not be halved.

Of course, if the maximum speed is never reached due to a limitation on the drive, it doesn't matter even if they were halved.

Usually, 2 USB ports close together are on the same controller and on a laptop usb ports on the left side are not on the same controller as those on the right side, but really cheap laptops may still put all ports on just one controller.